# Convert Expression<Func<TClass, TField>> to Expression<Func<TClass, object>>

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a generic "update expression builder" - an object that can be passed around, and used to indicate which fields need to be assigned what value.
What I did is :

```
public class UpdateExpression<TClass> : Dictionary<Expression<Func<TClass, object>>, object> 
{};

public class  UpdateExpressionBuilder<TClass>
{
    private UpdateExpression<TClass> fieldsValues;

    public UpdateExpressionBuilder()
    {
        fieldsValues = new UpdateExpression<TClass>();
    }

    public UpdateExpressionBuilder<TClass> Add<TField>(Expression<Func<TClass, TField>> field, TField value) 
    {
        fieldsValues.Add(field, value);
        return this;
    }

    public UpdateExpression<TClass> Build()
    {
        return fieldsValues;
    }
}
```

Which is meant to be used as:

```
var personUpdateExpression = new UpdateExpressionBuilder<Person>()
            .Add(p => p.FirstName, "David")
            .Add(p => p.MiddleName, "A")
            .Build();
```

And then I can send personUpdateExpression as a parameter to any method, for example a database update.

The problem is that the call `fieldsValues.Add(field, value)`
does not compile. Error is:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TClass, TField>>' to
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TClass, object>>'
```

I tried adding constraints `where TField : class, new()`
but this did not change anything.

When changing the signature of Add to
`Add(Expression<Func<TClass, object>> field, object value)`
It works perfectly. However then I loose the compile time type checking, so that `Add(p => p.FirstName, 123)` will compile, but fail on runtime.

Comment: It may be worth editing your question title - you're not converting delegates, you're converting expression trees. That's somewhat different. Additionally, it's not clear what you'd actually do with the resulting expression trees. I suspect you'll find that you don't *want* a `Func<TClass, object>` as you'd need to convert back to the right field type. Perhaps you should just be storing a `List<Expression>`?

Comment: (Additionally, you'll need to do work to convert the expression tree to *fetch* a value into one to *set* a value. It's probably doable, but I would make sure it works for what you intend to do before you go further.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur completely to what Daisy wrote in its comments... Still you asked for something:

```
public UpdateExpressionBuilder<TClass> Add<TField>(Expression<Func<TClass, TField>> field, TField value)
{
    var body = field.Body;

    // Boxing for value types
    if (typeof(TField).IsValueType)
    {
        body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    }

    Expression<Func<TClass, object>> field2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, object>>(body, field.Parameters);

    fieldsValues.Add(field2, value);
    return this;
}
```

and then

```
var personUpdateExpression = new UpdateExpressionBuilder<Person>()
    .Add(p => p.FirstName, "David")
    .Add(p => p.MiddleName, "A")
    .Add(p => p.Age, 30)
    .Build();
```

Note that your example was string-only, but I've added an example for `int`.

In the end we rewrite the `Expression`. For reference types, nothing needs to be done other than changing the return type of the `Func<>`. For value types you need an explicit boxing.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the usage of this, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107134/how-set-value-a-property-selector-expressionfunct-tresult