# Set value with func pointing to the property

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a model:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Than I have a Func pointing to MyProperty:

```
Func<MyModel, int> func = x => x.MyProperty;
```

So, using this func I would like to change my property on initialized object:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
?????
```

Comment: What would be the role of `func`? Do you want to use it to point to the chosen property or use it as the actual setter?

Comment: Do you only have a `Func<,>`, or could you potentially re-engineer to an `Expression<Func<,>>`?

Comment: I want it to be a pointer. I can re-engineer to Expression.

Comment: @Rawling could you also provide example, how to achieve it with Expression<Func<,>>?

Comment: @Andrzej something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111631/215380) (assumes you have a model called `instanceEntity` to set the value on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the new value for "MyProperty" as an argument to your Func

```
    Func<MyModel,int, int> func = (x, newValue) => 
    {
        x.MyProperty = newValue;
        return newValue;
    };
```

And use it like this:

```
    var m = new MyModel();
    func(m, 2);
```

Alternatively, if you are not interested in the return value you can turn the Func into and Action:

```
Action<MyModel,int> func = (x, newValue) => x.MyProperty = newValue;
```

Also, you can capture the "MyModel" variable in a closure so that you don't pass the instance explicitly every time you want to change "MyProperty"'s value:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();    

Func<MyModel, Action<int>> getSetter = x => 
  newValue=>x.MyProperty = newValue;

var setter = getSetter(myModel);

setter(3);
setter(4);
```