# Threadpool.cs not found in win form

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

i want write a chatroom with c# and Tcp but i have Threadpool.cs not found error.

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGuId.png)

how to can i fix this ?
this is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        Socket socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPEndPoint ipServer = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIp.Text), int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
            socClient.Connect(ipServer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have the error in the screenshot. looks like you are accessing the ui components from a different thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve a cross-threading Exception in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868783/solve-a-cross-threading-exception-in-winforms)

Comment: no when i use 
``` 
socClient.Connect(ipServer); 
```
i have this error.

this not a ui |:

@EylM

Comment: That screenshot is because you have "Just My Code" debugging unticked in the Visual Studio options. "threadpool.cs" is not relevant here, it's the cross-threading that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your Server Side `Form1`

you tried to update your list box from another thread so you faced this issue

on other to solve it you have to change your code from this :

```
void Accept(IAsyncResult res)
{
    socClient = socServer.EndAccept(res);
    listMessage.Items.Add("Client Connected...");
}
```

to this

```
        private delegate void UpdateListDelegate();
        void Accept(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            socClient = socServer.EndAccept(res);
            listMessage.Invoke(new UpdateListDelegate(() =>
            {
                listMessage.Items.Add("Client Connected...");
            }));
        }
```

so the main key is to `Invoke` your element whenever you are not working with main UI Thread.

Comment: `IAsyncResult` is ancient, you should use `Task` along with `async` `await` instead

Comment: @Charlieface i agree,thats just another topic to talk about, just tried to give him the fastest solution based on his own code :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a cross-thread call. You can hack around that by using `Invoke`. But I would *strongly* advise you to switch to `async` `await`, which will maintain the current context.

```cs
 public partial class Client : Form
 {
     Socket socClient;

     public Client()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
         IPEndPoint ipServer = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtIp.Text), int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
         await socClient.ConnectAsync(ipServer);
     }
 }
```

I also suggest you think about whether you want to use raw sockets, as it's much easier to use `TcpClient`.